# Insert / Send RefNbr to another database in Acumatica ERP System

Tags: c#, acumatica, erp

I have created a payment in Checks and Payments screen of Acumatica screen and released it. Please refer to the following screenshot.

[image]

I've already create the following code to provide it.

```
  protected virtual void APPayment_RowPersisted(PXCache sender, PXRowPersistedEventArgs e)
  {
      string serverJade, dbJade, userJade, passJade;
      serverJade = Properties.Settings.Default.serverJade;
      dbJade = Properties.Settings.Default.dbJade;
      userJade = Properties.Settings.Default.userJade;
      passJade = Properties.Settings.Default.passJade;


      APPayment app = (APPayment)e.Row;
      if (e.Operation == PXDBOperation.Update && e.TranStatus == PXTranStatus.Completed)
      {
          if (app.DocType == APPaymentType.Check || app.DocType == APPaymentType.Prepayment)
          {
              if (app.RefNbr != null)
              {

                  using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server = " + serverJade + "; database = " + dbJade + "; user = " + userJade + "; password = " + passJade + ""))
                  {
                      con.Open();
                      //---- query to update a field in the table of another database -------//
                      string query = "Update EVMaster set AcuRefNo = '" + app.RefNbr + "' where VchNo = 'DD02/16-VIII/12206-VCH-01'";
                      using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, con))
                      {
                          SqlDataReader sdr = com.ExecuteReader();
                          sdr.Close();
                      }
                      con.Close();
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

I already tried to debug this code, but didn't work. And then I try to use this follwing code.

```
    protected virtual void APPayment_RowPersisted(PXCache sender, PXRowPersistedEventArgs e)
  {
      string serverJade, dbJade, userJade, passJade;
      serverJade = Properties.Settings.Default.serverJade;
      dbJade = Properties.Settings.Default.dbJade;
      userJade = Properties.Settings.Default.userJade;
      passJade = Properties.Settings.Default.passJade;


      APPayment app = (APPayment)e.Row;
          if (app.DocType == APPaymentType.Check || app.DocType == APPaymentType.Prepayment)
          {
              if (app.RefNbr != null)
              {

                  using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server = " + serverJade + "; database = " + dbJade + "; user = " + userJade + "; password = " + passJade + ""))
                  {
                      con.Open();
                      //---- query to update a field in the table of another database -------//
                      string query = "Update EVMaster set AcuRefNo = '" + app.RefNbr + "' where VchNo = 'DD02/16-VIII/12206-VCH-01'";
                      using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, con))
                      {
                          SqlDataReader sdr = com.ExecuteReader();
                          sdr.Close();
                      }
                      con.Close();
                  }
              }
          }
  }
```

The codes above is worked, I just remove the if condition (if (e.Operation == PXDBOperation.Update && e.TranStatus == PXTranStatus.Completed)
          {}).

But it's not my goal, I have to filter document only for Doc Status = 'printed' from the document, and this process will be executed when 'Release' button was clicked.

And also any idea how to get all records in APAdjust of the current document ? because I need to comparing adjgrefnbr in apadjust with refnbr in APInvoice based on adjgrefnbr (apadjust) = refnbr (apinvoice). So I can get also all records of APinvoice based on refnbr (APinvoice) = ajgrefnbr (current apadjust). This condition is used to make 'where' condition of query not have to be hardcoded, I will used variable to provide it.

any suggestions to sove this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an example showing how to extend Release process for checks and subscribe to RowPersisted handler for the APRegister DAC to save released document RefNbr to another database:

```
public class APPaymentEntryExt : PXGraphExtension<APPaymentEntry>
{
    public PXAction<APPayment> release;

    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Release", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Update, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Update)]
    [PXProcessButton]
    public IEnumerable Release(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
        PXGraph.InstanceCreated.AddHandler<APReleaseProcess>((graph) =>
        {
            graph.RowPersisted.AddHandler<APRegister>(APReleaseCheckProcess.APPaymentRowPersisted);
        });

        return Base.release.Press(adapter);
    }
}

public class APReleaseChecksExt : PXGraphExtension<APReleaseChecks>
{
    protected virtual void ReleaseChecksFilter_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        var row = e.Row as ReleaseChecksFilter;
        if (row == null) return;

        Base.APPaymentList.SetProcessDelegate(list =>
        {
            PXGraph.InstanceCreated.AddHandler<APReleaseProcess>((graph) =>
            {
                graph.RowPersisted.AddHandler<APRegister>(APReleaseCheckProcess.APPaymentRowPersisted);
            });

            APReleaseChecks.ReleasePayments(list, row.Action);
        });
    }
}
```

By executing quite simple BQL query you can access APAdjust records associated with released check within handler for the RowPersisted event:

```
public static class APReleaseCheckProcess
{
    public static void APPaymentRowPersisted(PXCache sender, PXRowPersistedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.TranStatus == PXTranStatus.Completed && e.Operation == PXDBOperation.Update)
        {
            var doc = e.Row as APPayment;
            if (doc != null && doc.Released == true)
            {
                // save RefNbr to another database

                foreach (APAdjust oldadj in PXSelect<APAdjust,
                    Where<
                        APAdjust.adjgDocType, Equal<Required<APPayment.docType>>,
                            And<APAdjust.adjgRefNbr, Equal<Required<APPayment.refNbr>>,
                            And<APAdjust.adjNbr, Less<Required<APPayment.lineCntr>>>>>>
                    .Select(sender.Graph, doc.DocType, doc.RefNbr, doc.LineCntr))
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```